# VS Setup project after installation launching the application second time is taking very long time

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

Hi I have made a setup project of eclipse and given shortcut of eclipse.exe in start menu as well as desktop.

After installing the setup.msi i am launching it either by desktop shortcut or start program, first time after installation application is opening very fast but after closing the application and again starting through shortcuts its taking very long time to launch it.
it showing message "Please wait while windows configure "Project Name"" for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest some tools(Licensed or free) which dont have above mentioned constraint?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Windows Installer detects missing resources and triggers a repair. Here is a similar discussion:
[installed shortcut causing install to rerun visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215458/installed-shortcut-causing-install-to-rerun-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Hey I am making installer tool for pre-configured eclipse and i am expecting there will be some changes on every open/close due to configuration change. I am not bothered if any changes has been made and i dont want it be checked by .msi. Can you please let me know some quick fix.

Comment: A solution is to make sure that the files which can be removed are not key members in their components. But this is not supported by Visual Studio, so you would need a different setup authoring tool.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this in Visual Studio :(

Comment: Can you please suggest some tools(Licensed or free) by which I can avoid above problem ?

Comment: You can try Advanced Installer: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/   You can also find a tools list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: I know I am irritating you but can you please tell about WiX, can we achieve this in WiX ?

Answer (score 0):

Following [mmx's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215458/installed-shortcut-causing-install-to-rerun-visual-studio-2010) advice, I looked at event log, which gave me some clues about why MSI is complaining.  In my case it was:

> Detection of product '{5BF6F4BA-4266-42E8-A376-EB341856049F}', feature
>   'DefaultFeature', component '{5BF6F4BA-4266-42E8-A376-EB341856049F}'
>   failed.  The resource 'C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My App\' does
>   not exist.

It didn't make sense, because I wasn't putting my app in that specific folder.  I was putting my app folder into another folder, as following:

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\Some Other Folder\My App\'

After searching through MSI files for a bit, I finally found the culprit.  If you look at the 'Application Folder' (in Visual Studio right click on your Setup MSI project -> View -> File System).  You'll see its DefaultLocation property is set to:

> [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]

The fix in my case was simply replacing it with the following:

> [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\Some Other Folder\My App

After doing that, MSI was no longer triggering repairs on startup.